# Change Default Persian Font

Tags: fonts

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to change its default Persian font because I think it looks bad. And I don't want to change the default English font. Is this possible? If it is, how should I do this?

Comment: Can you explain exactly which font you are referring to? Providing a screenshot might be helpful ;)

Comment: For example, Windows default Persian font.

Comment: By default, the packages `fonts-farsiweb` and `fonts-sil-scheherazade` are installed if you install Persian on Ubuntu. Do you have those packages installed?

Comment: Yes I have installed them.

Answer (score 8):

1. Create a config file for the font in the following path:

   ```
   $HOME/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
   ```

   and add these lines to it:

   ```xml
   <?xml version='1.0'?>
   <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
   <fontconfig>

    <match>
     <edit mode="prepend" name="family">
      <string>Vazir</string>
     </edit>
    </match>

    <dir>~/.local/share/fonts</dir>
    <dir>/usr/share/fonts/</dir>

   </fontconfig>
   ```

   I used **Vazir** font, if you want to use another font(e.g. **Tahoma**) you must change the `<string>Vazir</string>` to `<string>Tahoma</string>`.
2. Place your font in `~/.local/share/fonts`.

Comment: Thanks, works great. I just put the directory to my current fonts location.
`<dir>~/.fonts</dir>`

Comment: It works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can change your font configuration to change the font of only Persian texts.

Create/Edit a font config file:

`vim ~/.fonts.conf`

Paste this into it:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
        <match target="pattern">
                <test name="lang" compare="contains">
                        <string>az</string>
                </test>
                <test name="family">
                        <string>sans-serif</string>
                </test>
                <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="same">
                        <string>Noto Naskh Arabic</string>
                </edit>
        </match>

        <match target="pattern">
                <test name="lang" compare="contains">
                        <string>az</string>
                </test>
                <test name="family">
                        <string>serif</string>
                </test>
                <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="same">
                        <string>Noto Naskh Arabic</string>
                </edit>
        </match>
</fontconfig>
```

To use another font (e.g. `Vazir`) instead of `Noto Naskh Arabic`, if you have already installed `Vazir.ttf` font, run this:

`fc-list : family file | grep Vazir.ttf`

this will show an output like this:

`/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Vazir/vazir-font-master/dist/Vazir.ttf: Vazir`

The second part of the output (after `:`) is the actual name of the font which you should use.

Save it and it will make effect on every new application you open.

If you want to learn how to install a font, read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts).

**NOTE:** The `lang` property must be [ISO 639](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) compatible language tag, and Persian is tagged `fa`. But with `fa` it didn't change the fonts (I don't know why. I hope it works for you with `fa`), so I used `az` (Azerbaijani).

Answer (score 1):

The default Ubuntu font not support your interest Persian font but you have two solutions:

1. user other beauty persian support form and open source same as the [`Vazir`](https://rastikerdar.github.io/vazir-font/) or [`etc`](https://rastikerdar.github.io/).
2. but other solution If you need necessary Ubuntu Latin form use the [`font-forge`](https://fontforge.github.io/) and merge any favorite fonts.

And for change default font you can use the [`Ubuntu Tweak`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak) or [`unity tweak tool`](https://github.com/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool)